# Pagination in node js

Tags: node.js, pagination

Fetching remaining details on the next page is not working. Below is the code

```js
try{
    const {page =1 , limit = 9} =req.query;
    
    var BTtemplata=await Template.find({"groupName":"British Telecom"}).select("templateId templateName templateDescription templateImage deleteStatus").limit(limit * 1).skip((page -1 ) * limit);
    var Shtemplata=await Template.find({"groupName":"Schneider"}).select("templateId templateName templateDescription templateImage deleteStatus").limit((limit - 6)*1).skip((page -1 ) * limit);
    // const templates =await Template.find().limit(limit*1).skip((page -1) * limit);
    
    res.status(200).json(
        {  
            totalTemplates:((BTtemplata.length)+(Shtemplata.length)),
            groupName:[{"name":"BT",totalTemplate:BTtemplata.length,template:BTtemplata},{"name":"Schneider",totalTemplate:Shtemplata.length,template:Shtemplata}],   
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, it is better to use the following modules. To solve your problem and benefit from its other features. There is a Mongoose module called [mongoose-paginate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate) that does all this easily.

```
var query   = {"groupName":"British Telecom};
var options = {
    select:   'templateId templateName templateDescription templateImage deleteStatus',
    sort:     { date: -1 },
    populate: '',
    lean:     true,
    page:   1, 
    limit:    10
};

var BTtemplata = await Template.paginate(query, options)
```